# Disable input at click jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Through jQuery I would like to find a way to disable an input ONLY IF EMPTY on_ click of a button below.

This is the input:

```
<input type="text" min="0" id="toolset-maps-distance-center" name="toolset_maps_distance_center" class="form-control js-toolset-maps-distance-center js-wpv-filter-trigger" value="" required="" placeholder="Inserisci una posizione" autocomplete="off">
```

This is the button:

```
<button type="submit" class="wpv-submit-trigger js-wpv-submit-trigger btn">Recherche</button>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
jQuery('.wpv-submit-trigger.js-wpv-submit-trigger.btn').click(function(){
  jQuery('#toolset-maps-distance-center').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

The result in the console is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Is true\false how it is in your code? It should be either true or false.

Comment: I am sorry i leave the past attempt, now is correct.

Comment: Or try using `attr('diabled', 'disabled')` instead of `prop`

Comment: Thank you so much code_Ninja, but i tried the PiTiNiNjA code and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.wpv-submit-trigger.js-wpv-submit-trigger.btn').click(function() {
    //check if input is empty
    var ifInputIsEmpty = $('#toolset-maps-distance-center').val() === '';
    //set disabled attribute according to ifInputIsEmpty
    $('#toolset-maps-distance-center').prop('disabled', ifInputIsEmpty);
});
```

Comment: you should always add an explanation to your answer, this helps avoid a copy/paste generation of developers and helps the OP to understand their mistake

Comment: This is perfect, Thank you

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Your comment was faster than my edit ;)

Answer (score 0):

please try this.
Check the value of input field and if it is empty, just disable it.

```
jQuery('.wpv-submit-trigger.js-wpv-submit-trigger.btn').click(function(){
  var inputValue=jQuery('#toolset-maps-distance-center').val();
    if(!inputValue)
    {        
      jQuery('#toolset-maps-distance-center').attr('disabled','true');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but i tried the PiTiNiNjA code and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

try this code

check `input` value in `if` condition

`if ($('#toolset-maps-distance-center').val() == '')`

```js
jQuery('.wpv-submit-trigger.js-wpv-submit-trigger.btn').click(function() {
  if ($('#toolset-maps-distance-center').val() == '') {
    jQuery('#toolset-maps-distance-center').prop('disabled', true);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" min="0" id="toolset-maps-distance-center" name="toolset_maps_distance_center" class="form-control js-toolset-maps-distance-center js-wpv-filter-trigger" value="" required="" placeholder="Inserisci una posizione" autocomplete="off">
<button type="submit" class="wpv-submit-trigger js-wpv-submit-trigger btn">Recherche</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but i tried the PiTiNiNjA code and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

As per i understand, you want the submit button to disabled when input is empty. For that try this:

```js
if ($.trim($('.kind').val()).length === 0){
  $('.kind').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

```html
<input class="kind" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Kind">

    <button class="submit" >Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but i tried the PiTiNiNjA code and it works perfectly